# How do I find the elements inside this "document"? Spotify API

Tags: javascript, spotify, profile

I'm following the Spotify API Web App Profile beginner guide: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/howtos/web-app-profile

I've done everything in the tutorial just fine, but I'm struggling on how to find out what elements are in the "document", and the "profile". Specifically, I want to see if there's a "currently listening to" element, or something similar. In the tutorial, it uses profile.id, profile.email, profile.uri, etc. I'm trying to see what else is in this "profile" object.

Here's my code:

```
const clientId = "[my ClientID is here]";
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const code = params.get("code");

if (!code) {
    redirectToAuthCodeFlow(clientId);
} else {
    const accessToken = await getAccessToken(clientId, code);
    const profile = await fetchProfile(accessToken);
    populateUI(profile);
}


export async function redirectToAuthCodeFlow(clientId) {
    const verifier = generateCodeVerifier(128);
    const challenge = await generateCodeChallenge(verifier);

    localStorage.setItem("verifier", verifier);

    const params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append("client_id", clientId);
    params.append("response_type", "code");
    params.append("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:5173/callback");
    params.append("scope", "user-read-private user-read-email");
    params.append("code_challenge_method", "S256");
    params.append("code_challenge", challenge);

    document.location = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?${params.toString()}`;
}

function generateCodeVerifier(length) {
    let text = '';
    let possible = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    }
    return text;
}

async function generateCodeChallenge(codeVerifier) {
    const data = new TextEncoder().encode(codeVerifier);
    const digest = await window.crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', data);
    return btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, [...new Uint8Array(digest)]))
        .replace(/\+/g, '-')
        .replace(/\//g, '_')
        .replace(/=+$/, '');
}


export async function getAccessToken(clientId, code) {
    const verifier = localStorage.getItem("verifier");

    const params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append("client_id", clientId);
    params.append("grant_type", "authorization_code");
    params.append("code", code);
    params.append("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:5173/callback");
    params.append("code_verifier", verifier);

    const result = await fetch("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
        body: params
    });

    const { access_token } = await result.json();
    return access_token;
}

async function fetchProfile(token) {
    const result = await fetch("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me", {
        method: "GET", headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
    });

    return await result.json();
}

function populateUI(profile) {
    document.getElementById("displayName").innerText = profile.display_name;
    if (profile.images[0]) {
        const profileImage = new Image(200, 200);
        profileImage.src = profile.images[0].url;
        document.getElementById("avatar").appendChild(profileImage);
        document.getElementById("imgUrl").innerText = profile.images[0].url;
    }
    document.getElementById("id").innerText = profile.id;
    document.getElementById("email").innerText = profile.email;
    document.getElementById("uri").innerText = profile.uri;
    document.getElementById("uri").setAttribute("href", profile.external_urls.spotify);
    document.getElementById("url").innerText = profile.href;
    document.getElementById("url").setAttribute("href", profile.href);
}
```

I've tried iterating through it, but I'm honestly not sure how to see the results, nor if my iteration is actually working.

Here's a link to Spotify's Web API: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api
I've tried to find a list of what's in the profile, but I can't seem to.

Comment: `console.log(profile)` just after `const profile = await fetchProfile(accessToken);` - then you'll see exactly what's in `profile`!